Purpose of Layout.cshtml in Blazor server app
Coming from an ASP.NET MVC background, I cannot understand the purpose of Layout.cshtml in a Blazor app. There is also a MainLayout.razor.  I know one is a view (.cshtml) and another is a component (.razor).
But if razor components can't be used within views, I don't understand the point of the layout.
For what purpose should I use Layout.cshtml and Mainlayout.razor?

Which version of Blazor are we talking about?
